How to search for some text in all the branches for a specific repo in Azure Devops web interface?
I have a repo on my local Visual Studio in Windows. The repo has tens of branches in Azure Devops.
I know that one of the branches has some new code based on some text. However I don't know which branch it is. How do I search across all the branches in a repo for some text?
The web interface allows me to search only one branch at a time.
Locally on my machine I only have the master branch. I don't have all the branches fetched from remote. (in case the solution is doing a search using git)
